# Inconsistent behaviour: CUDA 8 on GTX 1080

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I'm experiencing an inconsistent behaviour while running my code using Cuda 8 on a GTX 1080.
If I try to run this code on my GTX 1080 (Ubuntu 16.04, Cuda 8)

```c
__global__
void setValue(int *ptr, int index, int val)
{
        ptr[index] = val;
}

void foo(int size)
{
        int *data;
        CudaSafeCall(cudaMallocManaged(&data, size*sizeof(int)));
        memset(data, 0, size*sizeof(int));
        setValue<<<1,1>>>(data, size/2, 5);
        CudaCheckError();
        CudaSafeCall(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
        //useData(data);
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
                printf("%u %u\n",i,data[i]);
        CudaSafeCall(cudaFree(data));
}


int main()
{
        foo(5);
}
```

I get the following output

```
 0 0
 1 0
 2 0
 3 0
 4 0
```

while if I run it on a machine with a GeForce GT 740 and Cuda 7 I get

```
 0 0
 1 0
 2 5
 3 0
 4 0
```

I really cannot explain this behavior. I'm checking the CudaErrors but everything is ok even on the faulty code.
Any hint about how I can debug this behaviour?
[EDIT I was showing the output of the code in a wrong way]

Comment: Are you even sure that  any CUDA code runs correctly on the  Pascal machine?

Answer (score 1):

After two days of troubleshooting I got an answer for this.
The problem was caused by the driver installed by the nvidia installer (both the runfile or the .deb available from the CUDA download sections)
My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 x64

By using the driver available at https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa I got the correct behaviour.